# Api Gateway corrupt requests dictionaries

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm doing some request to an Api Gateway Endpoint. This Endpoint invoke a Lambda function.

Parameters containing a dictionary like this **{ en: 'Cartoon Boing', it: 'Boing' }** arrive at the Lambda function as string **{en=Hello, it=Ciao}**

Firstly I was thinking about an Api Gateway Mapping Template problem. (**title** is the dictionary)

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#set($title = $inputRoot.title)
{
    "userid": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "title":#if($title)"$util.escapeJavaScript($title)"#{else}null#end
}
```

I have also tried to avoid the javascript parsing but nothing change.

```
"title":#if($title)"$title"#{else}null#end,
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the corruption? Are the values actually changing i.e. Cartoon Boing -> Hello? Are you using a javascript Lambda function? Maybe show an example of the Lambda code that is using the dictionary/string